# Get td parent and tr child

Tags: javascript, html-table

I need to get the value "TEST1" from the first TD clicking on the button. I tried the Javascript but it doesn't work.. The print gave me undefined.

```
   <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <td>TEST1</td>
            <td>TEST2</td>
            <td><button class='x' type='button' onclick='openindex()' >value='button'</button></td>
        </tr>   
    </table>
```

Here is my Javascript function, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong because I find the closest Tr but the child property doesn't work

```
function openindex(){
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
        $tds = $row.find("td:nth-child(1)").value;
 alert($tds);
}
```

Comment: Please oh please, do not use PHP-style variable names with the leading dollar sign in Javascript.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes — It's a common pattern to indicate that the variable holds a jQuery instance.

Comment: @niels looks a lot like jQuery

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `openindex()` without an explicitly context, so `this` (inside it) will be `window` and not the element.

You could pass it:

```
onclick="openindex.call(this)"
```

but you should avoid using `onclick` attributes in the first place and bind your functions with `jQuery().on` instead.

```
jQuery('button').on('click', openindex);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to use

```
$tds = $row.find("td:nth-child(1)").text();
```

instead of

```
$tds = $row.find("td:nth-child(1)").value;
```

You should also use the var keyword to set the variable so it is not a global variable and since it is just returning a string there is no need for the $ so

```
 var tds = $row.find("td:nth-child(1)").text();
```

Or another way altogether would be

```
$('.x').click(function () {
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var tds = $row.find('td').first().text();
    alert(tds);
 })
```